# Import issues with flask app

Tags: python, flask

I had the following structure in my flask app:

`app.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from models import *
```

`models.py`:

```
from app import db
```

It worked fine until I wanted to do read/write operations on models in files other than app.py. I tried to import model `Trackorder` in a file `tasks.py` but got the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name TrackOrder
```

So, I changed the structure:

`__init__.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

But this makes `app` and `db` unavailable in `app.py` and `models.py`:

```
File "app.py", line 21, in <module>
    from models import *
  File "/home/nish/repos/stage/voylla_api/models.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Product(db.Model):
NameError: name 'db' is not defined

##after commenting models.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 210, in <module>
    @app.route('/')
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: tasks.py is in the same folder with app.py?

Comment: In which file did you try to import tasks.Trackorder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that could work for you.

Create a file named `core.py` (or whatever you want to name it):

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Now in `app.py`:

```
from core import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

# Instead of this line: db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# Use this approach to initialize db
db.init_app(app)
```

In your `models.py` you can use this import `from core import db`

This is based on the example here: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code with all import statement it's hard to say, but you most likely have a cyclic import. You are importing module B in module A and module B in module A.
This has the side-effect, that at the time you are importing A into B (the import that closes the cycle) nothing below the import of B is available in A. An example:

```
a.py:
from b import * # Now b.py is evaluated before the execution contiues.
var1 = 0

b.py:
import a
print(a.var1) # This raises an error since var1=0 was not executed yet.
```

Solution:
Reorder your imports or use the `import` statement locally, like:

```
def function1():
    from a import var1
    print(var1)
```